# How can I create a new column in R with aggregated values from another column

Tags: r, aggregate, columnsorting, mutate, mutated

I would like to create a column with aggregated v[image: original.png]alues from the column country

To an aggregated/classified column of subregions. For example,[image: ideal.png]

Comment: Please [don’t post your data as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Instead, run `dput(dataname)` in R, replacing “dataname” with the name of your dataframe. Then [edit] your post and copy and paste the `dput()` result from R.

Comment: Also, where are you getting the subregion values from? Do you have a separate vector or dataframe that links countries to subregions?

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

To aggregate in R:

```
agg_df <- aggregate(df$YVAR, by=list(df$XVAR), FXN)
```

Where df is your data frame. YVAR is your response variable, XVAR is your independent variables, such as sub region, and FXN is what you want `aggregate()`  to do with your YVAR, such as `mean`  or `sum`  or `length` .

Here is the doc for more reading.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/aggregate